# Switching to postgresql for heroku deployment of rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rails application currently using sqlite3. Following this guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 I'm trying to switch to postgresql. I changed my gemfile but when I run bundle install I get this error:

Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.0/.gemtest
An error occured while installing pg (0.14.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.14.0'` succeeds before bundling.

so I try gem install pg -v '0.14.0' and get this error:

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.0/.gemtest

I found a few people with similar problems but I couldn't get it working. This is my first time trying to deploy a rails application so I don't have much intuition about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure postgres itself is installed / correct?
the pg gem is the rails adapter, but you also need postgres itself on the machine.

e.g.

```
brew install postgresql
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
cp /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.4/org.postgresql.postgres.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist
rails new myapp -D postgresql
...
bundle install (install pg gem)
```

Comment: Well, you were right that postgres wasn't installed, but after installing it nothing has changed. still getting the same error messages